# Word for subjecting an animal actor to extreme distress in order to film its "performance" for a film?

Tags: single-word-requests

The excellent answer to the Movies SE question [Did they torture and kill a monkey during the filming of Andromeda Strain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110281/45856) explains in detail that in the filming of this 1971 feature film the monkey was exposed to a high level of carbon dioxide in order to evoke a very convincing "performance" that it died in a horrible way. It was convincing because it was genuine; this experience was known to be extremely distressing, an the convulsing monkey was within seconds of death when it was revived with oxygen under [ASPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Society_for_the_Prevention_of_Cruelty_to_Animals) supervision. (American Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals; the film was released in 1971, things have changed)

I don't know if this meets a definition of *torture* because there was no attempt to coerce nor any threat; e.g. "tell us or we'll hurt you" nor if it meets a definition of *sadism* because I'm pretty sure nobody on the set nor viewers of the film derived any amount of pleasure from watching this.

**Question:** Is there a word for subjecting an individual or animal to a severe level of distress in order to evoke a very real display of suffering in order to film it for a movie and conveys that the experience was very distressing, without ambiguity?

Comment: I'd think that instances of this type of action are sufficiently few that it would be unlikely a single word was coined to describe it completely.

Comment: The closest word would be [***jeopardise***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/jeopardize) or [***imperil***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imperil) but they don't have the connotations of "evoking a very real display of suffering".

Comment: That reminds me of Stanley Kubrick who was known for stressing actors by making them perform scenes over and over till they appeared real, to his eyes.

Comment: @user121863 yes that's just the sort of thing... a mashup of that plus [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/542853/217285) gives *[Kubrickesque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kubrickesque)-like or [Kubrickian](https://kubrick.fandom.com/wiki/Kubrickian)-like abuse*. I wish there was (were?) a `few-word-request` tag ;-)

Comment: [**Coercion**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coercion) or [**Duress**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/duress), perhaps?

Comment: Animals used (even killed) in research labs are said to have been sacrificed.

Comment: An interesting question: _did_ viewers of the film derive any pleasure from watching this? Consider: Wise evidently judged that this extreme (& arduous) course was necessary for the sake of _verisimilitude_. The obvious reason is that verisimilitude is one of the hallmark characteristics of this genre of film (and novel -- it's Crichton oeuvre, even), and thus would make _Strain_ a better film. A better film is more enjoyable. QED: monkey was suffocated precisely to enhance audience enjoyment. They could have cut from waking to sleeping monkey; fakey, but gets the point across.

Comment: @Tom I only mentioned pleasure within the specific context of sadism, not realism. And experiencing pleasure from watching the suffering itself is not the same as enjoying a film due to its realism. That said, who knows why exactly so many people like Crichton's stuff, but they certainly do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use the word ***abuse*** as a verb.  Torture is close but it's not really pain that's intended but the appearance of pain, the distress felt by the monkey is almost incidental.
I wouldn't argue against the use of the word ***Torture*** but I think I'd use ***Abuse***, to speak of directors torturing actors to get the desired performance is common but it's a deliberate exaggeration for effect rather than an accusation of a crime.

Comment: "Abuse" conveys "treat badly" without implying much about the reasons for doing so, which evades the problems that come with terms like "torture." A good fit.